# How to GridView All Installed Apps

Tags: xml

How to GridView the All Installed Apps ;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Installed Apps"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

i want to Display the apps in GridView
Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your Xml file ;

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="6"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dip" />
```